# Changing my projects Json file to A Yaml file using Microsoft

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft.extensions.configuration

I am using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration and would like to change from Json to Yaml do to an sdk change. I have tried just changing `.json` to `.yml` and that did not work. I also tried to change `AddJsonFile` to `AddYamlFile` both did not work and I commented out the different attempts below.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AppiumTestingofmobileapps.Utility
{
    public static class ConfigurationBuilder
    {
        public static IConfiguration InitConfig()
        {
            //var config = new 

            ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.test.json").Build();
            //var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("browserstack.yml").Build();
            //var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddYamlFile("browserstack.yml").Build();
            return config;
```

Comment: Using Python it's very easy: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/convert-json-to-yaml-in-python But it's possible with c# also: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5314773/Cinchoo-ETL-Quick-Start-Converting-JSON-to-YAML-Fi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I saw there no default addYamlFile extension method in `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder` [ConfigurationBuilder Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-8.0) for yaml but I saw that there is a `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Yaml` that you can Install from nuget.

Comment: I don't see that in my Visual Studio Nuget Packages.

Comment: Here is a link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Yaml/2.0.0-preview2 to the package try to access it from there or install with the console. I don't know is not visible to you.

Comment: This package was released 7 years ago in _preview_ status. No further releases, no updates. Better find an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

[NetEscapades.Configuration.Yaml](https://github.com/andrewlock/NetEscapades.Configuration?tab=readme-ov-file#yaml-configuration-provider) can be used for that, it provides a YAML configuration provider with `AddYamlFile` method:

```
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder => 
        {
            builder.AddYamlFile("appsettings.yml", optional: false);
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```